# How to read Clipboard data from windows using Asp.Net Core 3.0.1

Tags: c#, clipboard, asp.net-core-3.0

> **I created a C# desktop application to generate XML File and save XML**
>   **file to Clipboard, now I need to read Clipboard using Asp.Net Core**
>   **3.0.1, How can I read Clipboard data using Asp.Net Core 3.0.1?**

This is the code that i used to generate XML and copy XML data to the Clipboard

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CardData));
FileStream fs;

fs = File.Create(FilePath);
serializer.Serialize(fs, cardData);
fs.Close();

var Data = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
Clipboard.SetText(Data);
```

And this is some resources I search:
1. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1265249/Read-Emirates-ID-in-a-Web-Application 
2. [.Net Core - copy to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205260/net-core-copy-to-clipboard)  
3. https://code-examples.net/en/q/2a284cc

Comment: There is no clipboard access in ASP.NET Core, because it runs on the server, whereas the clipboard is a client-side concept. You can access the clipboard via JavaScript and then use AJAX or something to send that to the server.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt, This help me to do the solution