# Clipboard Method Doesn't Exist

Tags: c#

I haven't used C# that much, but I wanted to try it since it was the best language for the project I'm working on, but I've tried to find how to save text to clipboard, and whenever I try `Clipboard.` it says "Cant resolve symbol Clipboard"

Comment: Please update post to show your attempt, we have no clue what code you're trying.

Comment: Add some info about the framework you use and the type of project is it WPF or winforms or console application, any way see these answer [.Net Core - copy to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205260/net-core-copy-to-clipboard) and [How do I copy the contents of a String to the clipboard in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205260/net-core-copy-to-clipboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a console application it doesn't automatically come with `System.Windows.Forms`, which is needed for `Clipboard`, to add it, add it to your references by right clicking the project in vs or edit csproj.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a .Net Core, the `Clipboard` can now be found in the `System.Windows` namespace; add that to your `using`s by selecting the squiggly lines or `Alt-Enter` to provide intellisense options for missing references.