# Asp.NetCore2.1 how to copy text in clipboard

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, clipboard, asp.net-core-2.1

How to copy text to clipboard in asp.net core 2.1 ?

i instal tetxcopy by nuget but version conflict occours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net Core - copy to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205260/net-core-copy-to-clipboard)

Comment: No , this way not work in asp core2.1

Comment: Could you please tell me where you want to copy the text on the client browser or else?